# JQuery $().each exiting too early

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, each

I'm using the function below to validate several input fields on a web form. The function iterates through the fields using jQuery `.each()` iteration. The `ValidateInput` function validates each individal input field, returning a true or false.

```
function ValidateForm() {
    var result = true;
    $('[data-regex]').each(function() {
        result = result && ValidateInput(this);
        // return true;
    });

    if ( result == false ) {
        $(".alert").show();
    }

    return result;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the `.each()` is terminating early, as soon as any individual input field fails validation. I know that if `function()` returns false, the `.each()` will terminate, but I don't see how I'm doing that. I've even tried adding an explicit `return true;` as the last line of `function()`, but this made no difference.

For completeness, here's `ValidateInput`:

```
function ValidateInput(thisInput) {
    var fieldName = $(thisInput).attr('name');
    var fieldValue = $(thisInput).val();
    var regex = $(thisInput).attr('data-regex');
    console.log('validating field "' + fieldName + '" value "' + fieldValue + '" with regEx "' + regex + '"';
    var re = new RegExp(regex);
    var result = re.test(fieldValue);
    if ( result ) {
        console.log('- passed');
        $(thisInput.closest(".form-group")).addClass("has-success").addClass("has-feedback")
    } else {
        console.log('- failed');
        $(thisInput.closest(".form-group")).addClass("has-error").addClass("has-feedback")
    };

    return result;
}
```

The code that calls `ValidateForm` is as follows:

```
<input type="submit" name="ct108" value="Save User" onclick="return ValidateForm();" />
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ValidateInput` method stops processing after the first one that doesn't pass validation because this line:

```
result = result && ValidateInput(this);
```

The way `&&` works is that if the item on the left side is truthy the value on the right is returned as the value, otherwise the value on the left is returned as the value.

You can guarantee that each one is processed by flipping it around:

```
result = ValidateInput(this) && result;
```

Comment: Thank you - that seems to have done the trick, but I'm more than a little confused still. Why does the addition of the `return true;` not override the return value of `function()`?

Comment: Ignore comment above - I get it now! Thanks again.